# Ring Switcher in Unity

Tags: 11.04, unity, windows

In classic GNOME2 desktop I could install Compiz and customize it with Compiz config settings manager so that clicking on a specific screen location allowed switching between open windows. With Unity can I do the same or `Alt` + `Tab` is the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiz Config works under Unity and the Ring Switcher does work.

Comment: For ring switcher I am able to use `Alt+Tab` combination but right edge + mouse clicks(I configured it that way) did not work. What could be the reason?