# Ring Switcher in Unity - Mouse combinations don't work

Tags: 11.04, compiz

I asked this question [Ring Switcher in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38061/ring-switcher-in-unity/38069#38069) for knowing, do ring switchers work in Unity? As answered there it works but only with keyboard shortcuts. I am able to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combination but right edge + mouse clicks(I configured it that way) did not work.

How can I set this right? Most of the times I work with mouse and this option is really handy for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. When I posted the same question in [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10780460), as my problem was not resolved, It was suggested that I add myself to those affected in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/761616).

Comment: Better you add only a comment to a bug report when you add new information.
But above each bug there is also: "This bug affects 16 people. Does this bug affect you?" Clicking here helps to count how many people are affected, without cluttering the bug report!

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` using Ubuntu Software Center or `apt-get`.
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Go to "Ring Switcher" and select the shortcut you want.

Comment: I have done everything before I asked the question. But mouse combinations do not work!

Comment: Have you tried to disable Ring Switcher, close ccsm, re-open, and re-enable?

Comment: Just tried that, it didn't work. Also if I disable and enable, all the items in top panel disappear. I need to log off and log in to see them again.

Comment: Weird. I will search more and post here if I find something new.