# Compiz Desktop Wall edge bindings not working

Tags: compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable bindings in Desktop Wall?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41058/how-can-i-enable-bindings-in-desktop-wall)

I have set in the *Desktop Wall Plugin ➜ Bindings* under gnome classic to use 'mouse 1 and left/right edge' to change workplace, but that does not work.

I have also set in 'command' to use 'bottom right corner and mouse 1' to run
 `nautilus --no-desktop`, but that also does not work.

How can I do this?